# Are there limitations to pseudo-class selector in incognito

Tags: css, incognito-mode

I am using the pseudo-class selector :visited on a link and the styles aren't visible in incognito mood only? I'm wondering both why and is this on purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The :visited CSS pseudo-class represents links that the user has already visited.

In incognito mode, the browser do not store the adress of the pages you visit (it is the purpose of this mode), so nothing will append with the styles...